# Cannot send POST data via FormData with AJAX if version of Jquery is 1.4

Tags: php, jquery, form-data

I have a service, which looks like this:

```
 values = new FormData();
 values.append("mpsRegnomer", $('#mpsRegnomer').val());
 alues.append("mpsMarka", $('#mpsMarka').val());

 $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'assets/clients/services/test.php',
     async: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     cache: false,
     dataType: "JSON",
     data: values,
     success:function(response){....
```

And in test.php:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Well if version of jquery is 1.10 or 1.12 `$_POST` is fill with data, but when jquery is 1.4.. `$_POST` is empty

Where am I wrong ?

P.S:

```
for(var pair of values.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
}
```

returns me same values for every version.

Comment: If 1.10 and 1.12 work, why not just use those? Ideally, move to a more recent version still.

Comment: Agree. `1.4` is quite ancient and probably predates FormData API

Comment: Yeah I know, but right now I cannot change version, probably in a few days, but I'm curious why is this happening.

Comment: Because you're using things unsupported in 1.4.

Comment: You could use `fetch()` in modern browsers or write your own `XMLHttpRequest` instead. `$.ajax` is a wrapper for `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: If not uploading files can use `$.serialize()` instead of FormData also

Comment: @charlietfl Uploading files :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is because `contentType` is only available from jQuery 1.6 and newer. This property is required when serialising FormData to ensure that it's encoded within the request properly. As you don't have access to it in jQuery 1.4, you cannot send FormData in an AJAX request.

However the bigger point is why are you using jQuery 1.4? It's nearly 10 years out of date.

Also, note that `async: false` is incredibly bad practice and should not be used. As you've defined a `success` handler function you don't need a synchronous request anyway

Comment: Hmm, yeah, but without `contentType: false,` data woud be unreadable in PHP. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: Yes, update the version of jQuery. Alternatively, use a plain JS `XMLHttpRequest` as @charlieftl suggested in the comments. See MDN for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Using_XMLHttpRequest_and_the_FormData_object